# MySQL Regular Expression Match

Tags: mysql, regex, concatenation

I am trying to update my product database and find duplicates after some product numbers where changed.

In the past the changed item numbers just had an extra dash and number or letter on the end and I used this where clause:

```
where a.ProdNum REGEXP CONCAT('^', b.ProdNum, '(\-|\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+')
```

Now the REGEXP is over my head.

Old Product number: BRB-0325

New Product number: 0325-15 (the number after the dash can be any 1 or 2 digit number)

So basically I need a where clause that will drop the "BRB-" from the Old Number and drop any 1 or 2 digit number after the new item number.

I can do the dropping of the "BRB-", but not sure how to handle dealing with the 1-2 digit number, and I really don't know how to do both at the same time.

```
where b.ProdNum = CONCAT('BRB-', c.ProdNum)
```

Here is what I tried with the 2 digits and that didn't work.

```
where c.ProdNum REGEXP CONCAT('^', b.ProdNum, '(\-)[0-9]{1,2}+')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where are the new digits supposed to come from?

Comment: I edited it to be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `c.ProdNum` is the new number and `b.ProdNum` is the old:

```
WHERE CONCAT('BRB-', c.ProdNum) REGEXP CONCAT('^', b.ProdNum, '-[0-9]{1,2}$')
```

This adds "BRB-" to the new number and compares it to the old. So you will be essentially comparing "BRB-0325-15" with "BRB-0325-nn".

Comment: This will not use indexes, due to the `CONCAT()` function on the left of the equals sign.

Comment: @RossSmithII Regular expressions by definition cannot use indexes anyway, correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: You're correct! I assumed MySQL would use an index if the regex began with a `^`, as it does for `LIKE "a%"`. Sorry for the noise!

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `REGEXP`? Use a straightforward comparison:

```
where a.ProdNum like concat(substring(b.ProdNum, 4), '-??')
```

This will match `0325-ab`, but surely you don't have such new product numbers.

Comment: Is a or b the new item number?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT
old.*
FROM
products old,
products new
WHERE new.ProdNum REGEXP CONCAT('^', SUBSTRING(old.ProdNum, 5), '-[0-9]{1,2}$')
AND   old.ProdNum LIKE 'BRB-%'
```

This should use an index on `ProdNum` if one is available.